# Java peer-to-peer thread model, everyone wait for Job

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, blockingqueue

This is a schoolwork.
I am trying to create peer-to-peer Thread model:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169479&seqNum=5

> Where the delegation model has a boss thread that delegates tasks to worker threads, **in the peer-to-peer model all the threads have an equal working status**. Although there is a single thread that initially creates all the threads needed to perform all the tasks, that thread is considered a worker thread and does no delegation. In this model, there is no centralized thread.

So my main thread willl create 5 threads, that start listening to my queue and also create jobs with main thread for 10 seconds. And since all threads must perform tasks, this thread must also wait for jobs. How can I do this?

```
BlockingQueue<Job> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Job>(1000);

    Collection<Thread> workers = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Worker(queue));
        workers.add(thread);
        thread.start();
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
    Random r = new Random();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
        try {
            CalculateJob job = new CalculateJob(r.nextInt(50), r.nextInt(50), r.nextInt(50));
            queue.put(job);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So my main thread will be working with creating threads, and workers are just sitting with `queue.take()`.

**Do I understand correctly that in peer-to-peer model, every thread must `queue.take()` or  wait for jobs. If so, how can I do this? Any suggestions?**

Comment: You already have answered to your question :)

Comment: @AmitD Yeah, but when I have my "main" Thread busy creating new jobs and adding them to queue, how can I also complete Jobs with that Thread?

Comment: Once one worker thread creates all job it can call take() on the queue. So your all workers are calling take() on queue so that it.

Comment: Yes. As I said in my answer if you want to block workers to work until Boss thread finishes then You can use `CountDownLatch`. every thread will call `await()` on latch and once Boss has finished it will open the gate and all threads can start work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked to doesn't say how jobs are created. They probably mean they are created from elsewhere. Looking at the figures for the respective models, we see that:

- In the "delegation model", the main thread decides which worker thread will perform the Job
- In the "peer to peer model", the peer threads get work from a common queue (and whichever thread happens to be first gets the next Job), so the peer threads coordinate themselves.

By using a ConcurrentQueue, you have actually implemented the peer to peer model.

To summarize, the distinction they make is how threads coordinate the work, not how the work is created.

Answer (score 1):

As Suggested the article you have provided itself

> in the peer-to-peer model all the threads have an equal working status. Although there is a single thread that initially creates all the threads needed to perform all the tasks, that thread is considered a worker thread and does no delegation

Your Boss thread which happens to be also worker will create jobs put in the queue and can act like worker by calling `take()` once it has finished with putting the jobs.

Now if you want to block all threads until Boss thread finishes creating jobs then you can use `CountDownLatch` with single count.

I really don't know whether this model has any advantage our producer/consumer model or not.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is tagged with [java](/questions/tagged/java) and because of the fact that *workcrew model* sounds as if it is a general concept of concurrency, I add psuedo-code in C.

> In the peer model, also known as the workcrew model, one thread must
>   create all the other peer threads when the program starts. This thread
>   subsequently acts as just another peer thread that processes requests,
>   or suspends itself waiting for the other peers to finish. The peer
>   model makes each thread responsible for its own input. A peer knows
>   its own input ahead of time, has its own private way of obtaining its
>   input, or shares a single point of input with other peers.

[image]

```
main()
{
   pthread_create( ... thread1 ... task1 )
   pthread_create( ... thread2 ... task2 )
   .
   .
   .
   signal all workers to start
   wait for all workers to finish
   do any clean up
}

task1()
{
   wait for start
   perform task, synchronize as needed if accessing shared resources
   done
}

task2()
{
   wait for start
   perform task, synchronize as needed if accessing shared resources
   done
}
```

All sources are quoted from [PThreads Programming - A POSIX Standard for Better Multiprocessing, Buttlar, Farrell, Nichols](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565921153.do)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only difference between **boss** and *peer-to-peer* is the type of
requests( ***input***). If requests are different types, than the program needs to figure which thread to call, that is a **boss** model, if requests are identical like multiplying matrices than it doesn't need a boss and we have *peer-to-peer* model.